# Can you use an OR in a switch?

Tags: c++

Can you use an OR operator in a switch case? I was trying to remove case sensitivity from a user input check (so there may be a better way to do this altogether, I'm a beginner after all), and this of course resulted in doubling my switch case (not including the default case). Would it be better to use an if/else at this point, or is there a way to check for different conditions in a case?

My code, if it helps:

```
    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
        cout << "Good, we will check later to ensure your opinion is unchanged." << endl;
        break;
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
        cout << "Open your window tonight, unlock the door, take sleep medication, and ignore any noises in your room." << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Not an answer... think you can play games with me? I'll give you worse than the lemon haters, you'll be better off killing yourself before I take matters into my own hands." << endl;
```

Comment: What you have shown will work just fine. You can have multiple `case` statements using fall-throughs to a single block, like you are doing. Otherwise, you could just lowercase/uppercase the input value that you are passing to `switch()`, then you can remove half of your `case` statements

Comment: You can use `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` to convert to a common lowercase or uppercase before the `switch`.

Comment: 1) This is a perfectly appropriate use of multiple "case" statements.  2) Having said that, `std::tolower` (with one case stmt) might be a better choice.  3) Finally, "No, you cannot use || in a case statement to achieve "'y' or 'Y'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not plan to distinguish whether letters are lowercase or uppercase, then the best solution would be to "convert" your switch variable to lower/uppercase. By that you will get rid of unnecessary cases and save some time in future while implementing new ones.

Depending on your decision, you may choose `std::tolower` or `std::toupper`:

```
switch (std::tolower(x)) {
    case 'y':
        std::cout << "answer1" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'n':
        std::cout << "answer2" << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "answer3" << std::endl; 
        break;
}
```

Answering your question about usage of OR statement - it will not work well with `char`. All characters are defined with some integers (values from ASCII table), which means that e.g. `y` has the value `121`, while `Y` has `89`.

Let's take a look at expression `case 'y' ||  'Y'`: the value returned from `'y' || 'Y'` would actually be `1`. How is that possible? OR statement returns `1` if at least one of arguments is not `0` and `0` otherwise. This is how the value is calculated:

```c
case 'y' ||  'Y'    =>    case 121 || 89    =>    case 1
```

Sadly, neither `y` nor `Y` is defined as `1` in ASCII, so switch will use `default` case with that input.

Answer (score 1):

you can use it but it will not work, why? let me explain

when pass variable to switch() c++ will compare its value and type with each case, when you use "or" is a logical operator that means the result of the comparison will be a boolean value, check this example:

```
int main()
{
char input = 'R';

switch(input){
    case 'R' || 'r' : // the 'or' opreator will return true wich is not equal to R   
        cout<<"wow!!!";
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"meh";
}


return 0;
}
```

solution: you can use if/else statement

```
 if(input=='Y' || input =='y'){
    cout<<"Good, we will check later to ensure your opinion is unchanged." << endl;
}else if(input=='N' || input =='n'){
    cout<<"Open your window tonight, unlock the door, take sleep medication, and ignore any noises in your room." << endl;
}else{
    cout << "Not an answer... think you can play games with me? I'll give you worse than the lemon haters, you'll be better off killing yourself before I take matters into my own hands." << endl;
}
```

**or you can use tolower() to force the input to be lower case **

Answer (score -1):

You can't use OR in a switch case, since it checks equality of the input and the case, so when using || evaluates to either true or false, which likely won't be equal to the input (for example, you check if a number, like 5, is equal to false). @Mohammed Khaled Gave a good explanation. What you can do is simply make an if/else chain (where you can use ||), or copy and paste the code from the switch cases.

```
 int a = some_value;

switch(a) {
    case 5:
        do_something_1;
    case 6:
        do_something_1;
    case 7:
        do_something_2;
}
```

Comment: copying-and-pasting code should be avoided at all costs per the DRY (don't-repeat-yourself) principle -- any duplicated code becomes a maintenance problem.  In any case, duplicated code isn't necessary here as the fall-through mechanism will give the same result (i.e. just delete the first instance of `do_something_1` in the above example and you have the desired behavior)

Btw, did you intend to include `break;` statements (at the end of each case) in your example?